# how can I add multiple setval statements inside the block in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

how can I add multiple setval statements(50 statements) inside the block.

```
 DO $$
 BEGIN

 SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('alerts.incident_log','incident_log_id'),coalesce(max(incident_log_id),0) +1, false) from alerts.incident_log;
 SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('alerts.nds_email_message','nds_email_message_id'),coalesce(max(nds_email_message_id),0) +1, false) from alerts.nds_email_message;
 SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('alerts.nds_fax_message','nds_fax_message_id'),coalesce(max(nds_fax_message_id),0) +1, false) from alerts.nds_fax_message;
---- 50 statements
end $$;

 Error occurred during SQL query execution

 Reason:
 SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data
   Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
   Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
```

Comment: Your `DO` block is not complete, and the error message has nothing to do with your use of the `setval` function.

Comment: Hi. I have updated script with end.

Comment: Use `perform` instead of `select`